# Manually starting a PSU lowers the output Voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I have a PSU. When I start it using a motherboard, I get a little over 5 and 12 volts on the respective lines. But when I manually start it (by connecting PS_ON to ground), I get only 4.2 Volts on the 5 Volt lines.

This is causing an issue with the hard-drives that I am powering with this PSU. How can I make it output exactly 5 Volts?

By the way, this is the PSU in question: http://www.enermaxusa.com/psu_emd625awt_ii_sli.php

Comment: perhaps it doesn't detect enough load and isn't starting up properly? http://www.silentpcreview.com/news652.html

Answer (score 0):

PC switching power supplies require a minimum load to function properly. If "starting by hand" meant that the PSU didn't have any load, this is perfectly acceptable - it is not designed for this. I usually use an old, dead disk, that spins up to test PSUs, that proved to be enough load to get things in order.

Comment: I will test this tonight.